# Why does implementing an ActiveRecord accessor change how time works?

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have narrowed down a bug I have to a very specific example. I cannot find a reason for this behaviour.

The behaviour is as such:

1. Assume an ActiveRecord (in my case it's `Offer`) with a datetime field (in my case it's `Scheduled_at`)
2. Set the field in a `Time.use_zone("UTC")` block.
3. With no other interventions, read `scheduled_at.hour` inside and outside of the block.
4. Assert the value inside and outside the block to be the same.
5. Rerun the above but only read `scheduled_at.hour` ouside of the block.
6. Assert it is the same as the values in step 4.

**This is all fine.**

Now we open the Offer class and do the following:

```
Offer.class_eval do
  def scheduled_at=(scheduled_at)
    write_attribute(:scheduled_at, scheduled_at)
  end

  def scheduled_at
    read_attribute(:scheduled_at)
  end
end
```

Run through the steps above and note we are OK until we get to step 6.

Now there is a side effect on `scheduled_at` which is sensitive to when we first read it!

**Q: What causes this? Is it expected? A bug?**

Code is below:

```
  def test_strangeness
    puts "first run"
    do_stuff

    puts "opening class"
    Offer.class_eval do
      def scheduled_at=(scheduled_at)
        write_attribute(:scheduled_at, scheduled_at)
      end

      def scheduled_at
        read_attribute(:scheduled_at)
      end
    end

    puts "second run"
    do_stuff
  end

  def do_stuff
    o1 = Offer.new
    Time.use_zone("UTC") do
      o1.scheduled_at = Time.new(2015, 1, 2, 3, 45, 56, 0)
      o1.scheduled_at.hour
    end
    hour1 = o1.scheduled_at.hour
    puts "hour1 is #{hour1}"

    o2 = Offer.new
    Time.use_zone("UTC") do
      o2.scheduled_at = Time.new(2015, 1, 2, 3, 45, 56, 0)
    end
    hour2 = o2.scheduled_at.hour
    puts "hour2 is #{hour2}"

    assert_equal hour1, hour2

  end
```

Comment: I ❤ ``def test_strangeness``

Comment: This looks like a memoization issue, since the only difference is that you are calling the getter inside the ``Time.use_zone("UTC") do; end`` in the first object. But I cannot what the exact issue is. It looks intended though.